# getting "exec ./bin/activemq: no such file or directory" on docker image run

Tags: docker

Using below Dockerfile

```
FROM docker.io/eclipse-temurin:11-jre

ENV ACTIVEMQ_HOME /opt/activemq

RUN mkdir -p /opt/activemq && chmod 755 /opt/activemq

COPY apache-activemq-5.17.1/. /opt/activemq/

RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y

RUN addgroup --system activemq && adduser --system --home $ACTIVEMQ_HOME --uid 10001 --group activemq&& chown -R activemq:activemq $ACTIVEMQ_HOME  && chown -h activemq:activemq $ACTIVEMQ_HOME 

USER 10001

WORKDIR $ACTIVEMQ_HOME

CMD ["./bin/activemq","console","-Djetty.host=0.0.0.0"]

EXPOSE 61616 8161
```

Build Docker Image using `docker build -t 123:11 .`

When I try to run the image using `docker run -it 123:11` getting `exec ./bin/activemq: no such file or directory`.

Same worked on one server and not working on other server.

Tried to overwrite with `--entrypoint /bin/bash` and verified the files were copied successfully.

Any reason it is working on one server but not on other?

I'm using Docker Desktop on Windows servers.

Comment: What is you specify the absolute path?

Comment: Does the binary have missing C shared-library dependencies you need to install?  (Try `docker run --rm 123:11 ldd ./bin/activemq`.)

Comment: Building the image using Docker Desktop on windows. I need to run this on AKS.